# Using the Tokenizer in openNLP

Tags: nlp, opennlp

I am getting the POS tagged text in R in the form of:

id    type     start    end      features 

 1      word      1           5          POS=NNP 

 2      word       7           8          POS=IN

.....

I want to retrieve the word that it has tagged for example instead of the column 'type' with all values as words retrieve the actual words. I can use scan_tokenizer, but problem comes in when there are forms like "isn't" the POS tagger breaks it into "is" and "not", which is great but the scan_tokenizer doesn't tokenize that way it just keeps it at "isn't". Can anyone please help me retrieve the word that R has tokenized and used to POS tag?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use Illinois POS tagger? It is easy to use and visualize:

http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/page/software_view/3

http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/demo/pos/?id=4

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for this. A few questions that come to my mind are: (1) Does it have the same accuracy levels as the maximum entropy model? (2) Can it work on a folder that has multiple files? I have also used the tree tagger which is capable of the second part but I am a bit concerned on some of the accuracy. While I like the Stanford Model but I don't know how to make it run on multiple files and obtain a structured output.

Comment: (1) In the paper presenting it, it is one of the state-of-the-of-the-art models. (2) Definitely possible for both of them. If you use them programmatically, you can read and parse each file, one by one.